# Get Variable from Load Page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a variable from a load page using jQuery and PHP. Let say if I have 2 pages. My `no-1.php` page will be a form display and I also have a `<select>` list that user have to choose the States and when user click, It loads a new `<select>` list from page `no-2.php` inside a `<div>`. User have to select Staff Name based on the state that user choose earlier on page-1.php`.

Here is the codes that I made

**no-1.php** (jQuery to call the function for user to make selection on state)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var p_id = $("#p_id").val(); //value from form on page no-1.php
    var pid = $("#pid").val(); //value from form on page no-1.php 
    $('#list').load('no-2.php', {
        "pid": pid,
        "p_id": p_id
    });
    $('#lokasi').change(function() { //#lokasi is the State that user choose
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "no-2.php",
            data: {
                mlk: $(this).val() //value of the state
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#list').html(data)
        });
    });
});
```

**no-2.php** (`<select>` list that user choose for the Staff Name base on the State)

```
<select name="staff" id="staff">
    //php to select data from db
    <option value="<?php echo $row_mlk['staff_id']; ?>" <?php if($row_mlk[ 'staff_id']==$ p_id){ echo "selected"; } ?> >
        <?php echo $row_mlk[ 'name']; ?>
    </option>
</select>
```

the update process is on page `no-1.php`. Other data can be update perfectly but just the staff from page `no-2.php` is not updated. Can someone show me the right way of doing it.

> Issue solved

I am able to do it! If someone need an answer or guide, this is the URL that I refer to. hope it helps,

https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/

Thanks to those who helped and for the time.

Comment: Cant you just load the options from other page and keep <select name="staff" id="staff"> on main page

Comment: thanks for the detail. Do you have an example/link I can take a look. I tried to do it but the `option` appear nothing. Is it put on a div like: `<select name="staff" id="staff"><div id="list"></div></select>` the div will be the option data on page no-2.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row_mlk[ 'staff_id']==$ p_id)
{
   echo 'selected="selected"';
}
```